# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: :точность числа слишком большая ошибка числа или значения

Tags: sql, oracle

Падает ошибка

> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : точность числа
>   слишком большая ошибка числа или значения

код:

```
procedure pPair2TwoStr(
  p_PAIR  in varchar2,
  p_LEFT  out varchar2,
  p_RIGHT out varchar2,
  p_SEP   in varchar2 default '_'
) is
  jSep  integer;
begin
  jSep := instr(p_PAIR, nvl(p_SEP,'_'));
  p_LEFT := substr(p_PAIR,1,jSep-1);
  p_RIGHT:= substr(p_PAIR,1+jSep);

  if instr(p_LEFT,' ') > 0 or instr(p_RIGHT,' ') > 0 then
    Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Референс не должен содержать пробелы!');
  end if;
end;
```

Сам вызов процедуры:

```
function fCRCatalogID2CtlID(
  pColvirReferenceCatalogID in varchar2
) return U_SUBSCR_CTL.ID%type
is
  sCode  U_SUBSCR_CTL.CODE%type;
  iYear  U_SUBSCR_CTL.YEAR%type;
  iCtlID U_SUBSCR_CTL.ID%type;
begin
  pPair2TwoStr(pColvirReferenceCatalogID, sCode, iYear);
  iCtlID := U_PkgSubCtl.fCodeYear2ID(sCode, iYear);
  return iCtlID;
end;
```

Никак не могу разобраться, буду рада помощи, спасибо

Comment: Добрый день. Какие значения у входных данных( переменные в процедуре),?

Comment: @АртемЧерепахин вот код, который идет перед вызовом function fCRCatalogID2CtlID(
  pColvirReferenceCatalogID in varchar2
) return U_SUBSCR_CTL.ID%type
is
  sCode  U_SUBSCR_CTL.CODE%type;
  iYear  U_SUBSCR_CTL.YEAR%type;
  iCtlID U_SUBSCR_CTL.ID%type;
begin
  pPair2TwoStr(pColvirReferenceCatalogID, sCode, iYear); извиняюсь, что в таком виде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело тут вот в чем. У Вас в процедуре `pPair2TwoStr` переменные `p_LEFT` и `p_RIGHT` неявно получает ограничение, допустим `varchar2(15)`, и при вызове процедуры значения из переменных `p_LEFT` и `p_RIGHT` пытаются записаться в `sCode  U_SUBSCR_CTL.CODE%type` и `iYear  U_SUBSCR_CTL.YEAR%type` в которых ограничения установлено меньше чем в процедуре.

Пример:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PTEST(I_PAR IN OUT NUMBER, II_PAR IN OUT VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    I_PAR := 15.6;
    II_PAR := 'POIUYTREWQLKJHGFDSA'; 
  END PTEST;
```

Получаем, что то вроде:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PTEST(I_PAR IN OUT NUMBER(3.4), II_PAR IN OUT VARCHAR2(19))
```

Теперь, если произвести вот такой вызов:

```
DECLARE 
  V_STR VARCHAR2(10);
  V_NUM NUMBER(3,4); 
BEGIN
  PTEST(V_NUM, V_STR);
END;
```

И получаем ошибку:

```
DECLARE
*
ошибка в строке 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : буфер символьных строк слишком маленький ошибка числа или значения 
ORA-06512: на  "MILLER.PTEST", line 7 
ORA-06512: на  line 8
```

Не сразу ясно, что происходит, так? А все очень просто, `V_STR VARCHAR2(10)` переопределила ограничение переменной `II_PAR` при ее явном вызове и запись строки длинной 19 символов в переменную всего в 10 символов привело к ошибке! Очень важно это понимать.
Что бы избежать этого, можно сделать так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PTEST(
                      I_PAR IN OUT CUSTOMERS.CUST_NUM%TYPE, 
                      II_PAR IN OUT CUSTOMERS.COMPANY%TYPE)
IS

BEGIN
  I_PAR := 15.6;
  II_PAR := 'POIUYTREWQLKJHGFDSA';
END PTEST;
```

Такой способ удобен тем, что при изменении полей таблицы автоматом меняются параметры процедур, что облегчает сопровождение кода хранимых процедур, не нужно менять все параметры связанные с данным полем!

Comment: спасибо огромное, за такой развернутый ответ!

Comment: пожалуйста, был рад помочь)